# Wget com coringa na url

Tags: wget

É possível usar o wget com url contendo coringa?, por exemplo:

```
wget http://files.www.url.com/pastaDownloads/*.pdf
```

Comment: Tente assim:  `wget -r --no-parent -A '*.pdf' http://files.www.url.com/pastaDownloads/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo o [manual do wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) e [essa resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117988/wget-with-wildcards-in-http-downloads) na parte Unix do Stack Exchange, é possível sim, e ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.pdf http://files.www.url.com/pastaDownloads/
```

Do manual, com tradução minha e do google translate:

> `-r -l1` significa recuperar recursivamente (veja Recursive Download no manual), com profundidade máxima = 1. `--no-parent` significa que as referências ao diretório pai são ignoradas (veja no manual Directory-Based Limits), e `-A.pdf` significa baixar apenas os arquivos PDF. `-A "*.pdf"` teria funcionado também (no manual em Recursive Accept/Reject Options).